# Hiding _jcr_content/rendition in cq5

Tags: aem

How to hide _jcr_content/rendition/someimage.png?? below is an example

http://www.example.com/content/dam/myproject/myimages/scott_reynolds.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png

I want to replace the above url like:

http://www.example.com/content/dam/myproject/myimages/scott_reynolds.jpg/cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png

Is there a way to mask/rewriting the url, excluding jcr:content

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat sparsely documented sling selector for the thumbnail renditions that you can use.

(content path including extension).thumb.(height).(width).png

http://www.example.com/content/dam/myproject/myimages/scott_reynolds.jpg.thumb.100.140.png